# Recoger body url externa javascript y cargarlo html

Tags: javascript, html5

Apreciados compañeros:

Me remito a enviar este pregunta por si alguien sabria responderla. Tengo una url externa (index4.html) en html de la que quisiera sacar el body y cargarlo en mi pagina actual html. 
Actualmente tengo este codigo en (index2.html):

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function makeHttpObject() {

  try {return new XMLHttpRequest();}
  catch (error) {}
  try {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}
  catch (error) {}
  try {return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
  catch (error) {}

  throw new Error("Could not create HTTP request object.");
}
var request = makeHttpObject();
request.open("GET", "index4.html", true);
request.send(null);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (request.readyState == 4)
  var cosa = request.responseText;
  var iFrameBody = cosa.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    alert(iFrameBody);

};

</script>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Codigo index4.html:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Hello world!!
</body>
<html>
```

Pero no consigo que me salga un alert y menos aun cargarlo en el body.

Si alguien respondiera quedo agradecido de antemano.
S@|u2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En tu `index2.html`, puedo ver los siguientes errores:

- En `if (request.readyState == 4)`, no esta usando llaves (`{}`), por lo que deberías estar recibiendo un error que dice `cosa` es `undefined`.
- No estas [validando correctamente la respuesta del servidor](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/AJAX/Primeros_Pasos#_Segundo_Paso_.E2.80.93_Procesando_la_respuesta_del_servidor_). Es decir, te falta ver que `request.status` sea exitoso ([`200`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#200)).
- `cosa` no es un objeto, es texto plano.

Para poder extraer el `body` del `texto` que se recibe tras la llamada ajax, podemos usar [`document.implementation.createHTMLDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createHTMLDocument) (`IE9+`)

El código final podría ser algo así:

```
function makeHttpObject()  {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, IE7+ ...
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  throw new Error("Could not create HTTP request object.");
}

var request = makeHttpObject();
request.open("GET", "index4.html", true);
request.send(null);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {

  // Si se establecion correctamente la conexion
  if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {

    // Si la respuesta es exitosa
    if (request.status === 200) {

      // Creamos un nuevo "Document"
      var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("doc");
      // Inyectamos el texto html recibido
      doc.documentElement.innerHTML = request.responseText;

      // Reemplazamos el body actual por el nuevo.
      document.body.innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML;
    }
  }
};
```

Lectura recomendada: [HTML to DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/HTML_to_DOM#Parsing_Complete_HTML_to_DOM)

Comment: Pruebo tu codigo y te digo algo. Marcos como siempre, gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: pruebo tu codigo en archivo html basico y el script que pones entre los <head>. No hace nada. Si pongo alert entre <script>alert; tu codigo </script> saca el alert pero nada de lo tuyo. ??

Comment: Ok realizado. Tuve que cambiar algun trozo de codigo, lo pongo como respuesta correcta.

Comment: No salia porque en tu codigo creas request  y luego usas httprequest  que dara undefines. Cambiandolo va ok.

Comment: y recoger un div en lugar del body?

Comment: sustituir doc.body.innerHTML;  por doc.getElementById("nombrediv").innerHTML;

Comment: @akenateb, gracias por tus comentarios. He corregido mi código.

Answer (score 1):

Al final lo que conseguido con este codigo (lo dejo por si a alguien mas le pudiera servir):

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getFrameContents()
{
 var iFrame =  document.getElementById('ifpaginaIframe');
 var iFrameBody;
 if ( iFrame.contentDocument )
 { // FF
  iFrameBody = iFrame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
 }
 else if ( iFrame.contentWindow )
 { // IE
  iFrameBody = iFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
 }
 
 alert(iFrameBody.innerHTML);
 
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload=getFrameContents();>
<iframe name="paginaIframe" id='ifpaginaIframe' src="index2.html" frameborder=0 width=0 height=0 scrolling="no"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

pero no me interpreta el contenido solo lo carga:

```html
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Se ve asi, tal cual. Ahora a ver si logro que lo interprete.
Gracias por la respuesta.
S@|u2

Comment: Tienes 2 respuestas a la pregunta y al parecer esta no cubre tus necesidades. Considera corregir o es su defecto eliminar esta respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a Marco tengo una respuesta funcional:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function makeHttpObject()  {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, IE7+ ...
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  throw new Error("Could not create HTTP request object.");
}

var request = makeHttpObject();
request.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1/sql/index2.html", true);
request.send(null);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {

  // Si se establecion correctamente la conexion
  if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {

    // Si la respuesta es exitosa
    if (request.status === 200) {

      // Creamos un nuevo "Document"
      var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("doc");
      // Inyectamos el texto html recibido
      doc.documentElement.innerHTML = request.responseText;
  alert(request.responseText);
      // Reemplazamos el body actual por el nuevo.
      document.body.innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML;
    }
  }
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Saludos y muxas gracias a todos!.

Comment: He corregido el error en mi respuesta, entiendo que esta respuesta estaría de mas.