# Como poder obtener el codigo html de respuesta de un servlet

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

buena tarde ingenieros, necesito atrapar el codigo html de un servlet para poder mostrar solo fragmentos de informacion, no pretendo modificar nada de contenido ni mucho menos afectar, solo necesito mostrar informacion especifica, adjunto una imagen de ejemplo de como muestro el servlet dentro de un iframe.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la liga de mi pagina ya en el servidor: http://testing.anfexi.com/Repuve/Home/Busca

he intentado atrapar el html con ajax utilizando este codigo pero no me arroja el codigo de la imagen sino otro, adjunto el codigo:

```
 var valCaptch = $("#captcha").val();
        var valPlaca = $("#placa").val();
        var valUrl = "http://www2.repuve.gob.mx:8080/ciudadania/servletconsulta"
        var valUrlfinal = valUrl + "?" + "placa=" + valPlaca + "&vin=" + "&folio=" + "&nrpv =" + "&captcha=" + valCaptch;

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: valUrlfinal,
            data: { placa: valPlaca, captcha: valCaptch },
            error : errors,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: success
        });
```

espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: Como recibes la respuesta del servidor en la funcion `success` y que es lo que estas enviando desde el servidor exactamente cuando llega una peticion `post`?

Comment: en el sucess como tal no esta recibiendo nada, olvide comentar esa linea y lo que envio es el formulario azulito, puedes agregarme a skype para una mejor expliacion? marvel_nemesis_11@live.com.mx

Comment: Puede que [esta respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39711/recoger-body-url-externa-javascript-y-cargarlo-html/39715#39715) te sea de ayudar.

Comment: De tu lado ¿Solo estas utilizando JQuery y html?. Porque puedes utilizar java y obtener la cadena con **URLConnection** y parserarla en un Servlet.

Comment: Si lo que te esta mandando es algo como esto: **XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www...... Redirect from 'http://www.... has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.**. Esto no te lo mandaría a menos de que estuvieran en el mismo dominio. Aquí la explicación: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource] . Para esto si te serviría Java

Answer (score 1):

En las páginas web hay código de servidor y código de cliente.  El código de servidor se ejecuta antes de enviarte los datos, luego lo recibes en el navegador y luego se procesa el código de cliente (javascript).  Lo que te está pasando es que el re-captcha, no viene procesado del server, solo llega el script que, una vez que ha llegado la página a tu navegador, será ejecutado.

Dicho esto, la única forma que tienes para obtener esa imagen, es dejar que se procese el código de cliente una vez que lo has recibido en un contenedor como un iFrame, y luego utilizar una librería que te ayude a buscar elementos DOM (que no son más que los tags de HTML) como jQuery para buscar la imagen que se ha generado al final.

Esta no es una solución 100% segura, ya que no sabes cómo se genera ese re-captcha, es posible que venga en base 64, por lo que deberás lees el contenido en lugar de bajar la imagen.  Es posible que lo cambie dinámicamente, es posible que esté en un canvas, etc.  Sobre todo con los re-captchas que precisamente están pensados para evitar procesos automatizados, puede ser complicado.

Comment: hola jmdiego, no es como tal una imagen, sino es el contenido de un servlet, y con esto me ha quedado mas claro el por que javascript no me atrapa el contenido que necesito, puedes agregarme a skype para hacerte una pregunta mas a fondo por favor? marvel_nemesis_11@live.com.mx ,  gracias por esta breve explicacion